# display:none bug in IE8 regarding dom parsing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Need help in IE8.

There are many divs in my code with property `"display:none"` style

```
<div>
     <div id=div1 style="display:none">
        ....some lines of code....
     </div>
     <div id=div2 style="display:none">
        ....some lines of code....
     </div>
     <div id=div3 style="display:none">
        ....some lines of code....
     </div>
     <div id=div4 style="display:none">
        ....some lines of code....
     </div>
</div> //outer div
```

In the jquery code the divs are displayed dynamically using show and hide based on conditions.

The height of one div (e.g) div1 = 100px
where as height of another div (e.g) div4 = 1000px

The problem is, 
     when the page loads the div1 with lowest height 100px is displayed and when the other divs are displayed using show function. They get overlapped with the footers.

If the height for the outer div is set to the maximum divs height ie. 1000px, then when the other divs are displayed the page is needlessly long.

Even when the outer divs max-height is set to 1000px, it is not dynamically changing and the overlap occurs.

Resizing the window changes the height dynamically. But the resize of window does not work when other tabs are open. also a minimal change of window size is not enough to get rid of the overlapping.

Tried changing display:none to visibility:hidden but the page is needlessly long for the min height divs.

This occurs only in IE8, dont know about the browsers below its version. Works perfectly in IE9, chrome and mozilla.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or pastebin sample?

Comment: You provide the markup but the css and code would go a long way in getting actual help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the answer for this,

Instead of resizing the window, Adding the code after the show /hide

```
//Javascript
document.body.className = document.body.className;

//Jquery
$('body')[0].className = $('body')[0].className;
```

works fine

Thanks.